# algorithms in margin of tufte style book?

Tags: margins, algorithms, algorithm2e, tufte

I would like to place an algorithm in the margin of a tufte style book. I am using algorithm2e. I have no idea how to do this, or if it is possible at all. Please help? Here is an example but it place the algorithm in the main body and not in the margin:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\While{hungry}{
make cookies\;
eat cookies\;
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting it inside `marginfigure` environment?

[image]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext[1]

\begin{marginfigure}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\While{hungry}{
    make cookies; \newline
    eat cookies; 
}
\caption{Story of my life}
\end{algorithm}
\end{marginfigure}

\Blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is it :-)